# Добавить mime-type в htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, видео

Необходимо проигрывать видео формата mpeg на сайте. Пытаюсь использовать для этого jPlayer. Все подключил и настроил. Но видео не грузится, консоль пишет:

```
HTTP "Content-Type" типа "video/mpeg" не поддерживается. Не удалось загрузить медиаресурс
```

Добавляю в .htaccess такую строчку:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c> 
    AddType video/mpeg .mpeg .mpg .mpe
</IfModule>
```

Но мой браузер продолжает писать об ошибке.
Пробовал и без IfModule - ничего не изменилось.

Answer (score 1):

Браузеры не поддерживают видео в контейнере mpeg, нужно перекодировать его в один из поддерживаемых форматов/контейнеров: webm или mp4.